# Is there a plugin to create a folder and a file in it at the same time it terminal?

Tags: terminal

At the moment this is what I need to do

```
mkdir someFolder
touch someFolder/file.md
```

Is there a way to create both in one go (not using `&`). I'm thinking

```
mkTouch folder/file.md
```

Comment: You just write a simple shell script - many tutorials are on the wen

Comment: Try `mkdir someFolder; touch someFolder/file.md`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bash, add the following function to your `.bash_profile`:

```
mkTouch() {
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1"
}
```

Then, you can use `mkTouch folder/file.md`.